# 'Neural_Network' object has no attribute 'w1', but I think it does

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to get into Neural Networks and wanted to test some code from a video I am watching, but I keep getting the error, " Neural_Network object has no attribute w1", and I can't seem to figure it out. I went through many related stackoverflows, but they don't seem to answer the question, and since I haven't done any object-oriented programming for python before, I do not understand what is going on.

When I looked through the code, I thought that self.w1 was being set as a local variable so I tried to instantiate it and set is as a global variable above the constructor declaration, but that didn't work.

```
import numpy as np
class Neural_Network(object):

def _init_(self):
    self.inputLayerSize = 2
    self.outputLayerSize = 1
    self.hiddenLayerSize = 3

    self.w1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
    self.w2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize)

def forward(self, x):
    self.z2= np.dot(x, self.w1)
    self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.layer1)
    self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2,self.w2)
    yhat = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
    return yhat


def sigmoid(self, x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

x = np.array(([3,5],[5,1],[10,2]),dtype=float)
y = np.array((([75],[82],[93])),dtype=float)
n1 = Neural_Network()
yhat = n1.forward(x)
print(yhat)
```

The code should produce a matrix that states possible grades given a specified input 'x'.

something like: x = [[2,3],[5,2]]
                output: [[82],[93],[100]]

Comment: Is the code you've pasted here indented properly? Python is sensitive to indentation, please check that `forward` and such are actually under `Neural_Network`. Also, `_init_` should probably be `__init__` (double underscores).

Answer (score 0):

`init` should have two underscores surrounding it like:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Without two underscores on each side, Python does not call the function when the object is instantiated. In general, all such special functions and attributes have a pair of double underscores.

Answer (score 0):

This noob errors just kills me, i also found it not instantly:

- *init* with one _ is not cound as init so while Neural_Network() nothing was executed
- Inheriting from Object is always, dont write that
- then you ll notice the hidden layer self.layer1 was not defined
- then, do not give variable names one letter + digit, like w1, its very confusing with wl, etc
- Ahh also its important, you may not have output [75],[82],[93], because sigmoid as you remember have range from 0 to 1, the same for input. Make sigmoida for input and choose clear outputs, means only 0 or 1

  ```
  import numpy as np
  class Neural_Network:

  def __init__(self):
      self.inputLayerSize = 2
      self.outputLayerSize = 1
      self.hiddenLayerSize = 3

      self.w_h = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize, self.hiddenLayerSize)
      self.w_o = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize)

      self.layer_hidden = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize)

  def forward(self, x):
      self.z2= np.dot(x, self.w_h)
      self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.layer_hidden)
      self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2,self.w_o)
      yhat = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
      return yhat


  def sigmoid(self, x):
      return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
  ```

  x = np.array(([3,5],[5,1],[10,2]),dtype=float)
          y = np.array((([75],[82],[93])),dtype=float)
          n1 = Neural_Network()
          yhat = n1.forward(x)
          print(yhat)